# What blockchain (or similar technologies) allow for "splitting" the network, offline?

Tags: blockchain

There were a few ideas on how to make the blockchain hierarchical, and also splitting it to allow for splits.

Are there any proposed/non implemented ideas that accomplish this with Bitcoin or any technology?

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you mean by offline as you don't mention that in the body of your question at all.

I think one of the scalingbitcoin.org presentation in Hong Kong touched on what you are referring to.

Comment: Also, please specify what you mean with "splitting". Is that like forking but where the splits will be remerged later? Anyway, it doesn't seem obvious from your question.